# Using multiple libraries in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to use two libraries in the my tests. Is it possible?
If this is possible what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two libraries is the same as using one, or one hundred:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Selenium2Library
| Library | Collections
```